# Nicely managed lookup tables

Tags: postgresql, database-design

We have a `people` table, each `person` has a `gender` defined by a `gender_id` to a `genders` table,

```
| people    |
|-----------|
| id        |
| name      |
| gender_id |

| genders |
|---------|
| id      |
| name    |
```

Now, we want to allow people to create forms by themselves using a nice form builder. One of the elements we want to add is a select `list` with user defined `options`,

```
| lists |
|-------|
| id    |
| name  |

| list_options |
|--------------|
| id           |
| list_id      |
| label        |
| value        |
```

However, they can't use the `genders` as a dropdown list because it's in a different table. They could create a new list with the same options as `genders` but this isn't very nice and if a new gender is added they'd need to add it in multiple places.

So we want to move the gender options into a list that the user can edit at will and will be reflected when a new person is created too.

What's the best way to move the `genders` into a `list` and `list_options` while still having a `gender_id` (or similar) column in the `people` table? Thoughts I've had so far include;

1. Create a 'magic' list with a known id and always assume that this contains the gender options.

   - Not a great fan of this because it sounds like using 'magic' numbers. The code will need some kind of 'map' between system level select boxes and what they mean
2. Instead of having a 'magic' list, move it out into an option that the user can choose so they have a choice which list contains the genders.

   - This isn't really much different, but the ID wouldn't be hardcoded. It would require more work looking through DB tables though
3. Have some kind of column(s) on the `lists` table that would mark it as pulling its options from another table.

   - Would likely require a lot more (and more complex) code to make this work.
4. Some kind of polymorphic table that I'm not sure how would work but I've just thought about and wanted to write down before I forget.

   - No idea how this would work because I've only just had the idea

Comment: 1) The text descriptions are not precise enough to be understood.  Please clean it up so that we can help you.  Use technical terms.  2) State an overall goal, what it is that you are trying to achieve.  A global gender list plus a gender list per people ?  In that case, who would use the global list, what purpose does it serve ?

Comment: How many rows do you expect to exist in the final `genders` table ?

Comment: @wildplasser `genders` would probably only have ~3 options (unless a user wanted to add more). But the solution would be for any field that could have a known number of possible choices (gender, age range, country). Ideally these would all be stored within 1 table that could be used by both system defined tables (e.g. people) as well as user generated forms via the system, allowing us to add 1 extra gender/county to the list and it be visible wherever that list is in use.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would change your `list_options` table to a view.  If you have multiple tables you need have a list drop down for to pull from this table, just UNION result sets together.

```
SELECT 
   (your list id here) -- make this a part primary key
   id, -- and this a part primary key
   Name,
FROM dbo.Genders 

UNION 

SELECT 
   (your list id here) -- make this a part primary key
   id, -- and this a part primary key
   Name,
FROM dbo.SomeOtherTable
```

This way it's automatically updated anytime the data changes.  Now you are going to want to test this, as if this gets big it might get slow, you can get around this by only pulling all this information once in your application (or say cache it for 30 minutes and then refresh just in case).

Your second option is to create a table `list_options`  and then create a procedure (etc.) which goes through all the other lookup tables and pulls the information to compile it.  This will be faster for application performance, but it will require you to keep it all in sync.  The easiest way to handle this one is to create a series of triggers which will rebuild portions (or the entire) list_options table when something in the look up tables is changed.  In this one, I would suggest moving away from creating a automatically generated primary key and move to a composite key, like I mentioned with the views.  Since this is going to be rebuilt, the id will change, so it's best to not having anything think that value is at all stable.  With the composite (list_id,lookup_Id) it should always be the same no matter how many times that row is inserted into the table.